# Access query IIF statement not displaying result

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, iif

This should be a simple one but I have so far been unsuccessful. In access query, I am using the expression builder within a query to pull information from a table.

```
FirstName: IIf(Len([tbl_Associate].[NICKNAME])=0,[tbl_Associate].[FIRST_NAME],[tbl_Associate].[NICKNAME])
```

2 fields - one for First Name and one for nickname. If the nickname is blank display the first name otherwise give me the nickname. When I run the query, the results are only showing the nicknames and all others are blank.

This is a display query only, not updating any tables.

Comment: Len will return null on an empty record, not 0. Use `[tbl_Associate].[NICKNAME] Is Null`

Comment: @Warcupine that worked! Thank you. Funny enough I used the same table in another query with the same logic and it worked. Go figure.

Comment: Len(Null) returns Null, Len("") returns 0. Does field have Null or empty string? I don't allow empty string in fields. Could just use `Nz([Nickname], [First_Name])`.